# Display attributes in a table

Tags: java, javafx, properties, tableview

I have to populate a 2 column table in javafx and I was wondering what was the best way of doing it?

Basically I have this class

```
public class Name {

    private String _name;
    private Rating _rating;

    public Name(String name , Rating rating) {
        _name = name;
        _rating = Rating.NO_RATING;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return _name;
    }

    public Rating getRating() {
        return _rating;
    }
}
```

I want to populate a table in javafx to have one column with the name and one column with a rating. I have tried populating through name class and using getName() getRating() methods but that is not working. I searched online and there are a thing called properties but how would I use properties in this case since I don't have any properties?

Comment: Please format your code. " but that is not working" - show what you did.

Comment: Your fields seem to be immutable; I recommend adding the `final` keyword in cases like this. I'm not sure why you don't use the constructor parameter for the `_rating` field though. If you're ok with the immutability of your items, just use `new PropertyValueFactory("name")` and `new PropertyValueFactory("rating")` as `cellValueFactory`s in your columns.

Answer (score 1):

In the data model, warp the attributes you want to show in the table with properties :

```
//data model 
public class Name {

    private SimpleStringProperty name;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty rating;

    public Name(String name , int rating) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.rating = new SimpleIntegerProperty(rating);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rating.get();
    }
}
```

And use those properties in the table columns

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewDemo extends Application {

    private final ObservableList<Name> data =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new Name("Jacob", 12),
                    new Name("Isabella", 14),
                    new Name("Ethan", 5),
                    new Name("Emma", 17),
                    new Name("Michael",9));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");

        TableColumn<Name, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

        TableColumn<Name, Integer> ratingCol =  new TableColumn<>("Rating");
        ratingCol.setMinWidth(100);
        ratingCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Name, Integer>("rating"));
        final TableView<Name> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, ratingCol);

        Scene scene = new Scene(table);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**Edit** in response to  [kleopatra's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808531/display-attributes-in-a-table/52815086#comment92557018_52815086) :

You can also use properties as cell value factories. Change data model to :

```
public class Name {

    private SimpleStringProperty name;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty rating;

    public Name(String name , int rating) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.rating = new SimpleIntegerProperty(rating);
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() { return name ; }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty ratingProperty() { return rating; }
}
```

and define column by:

```
    TableColumn<Name, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
    nameCol.setMinWidth(100);

    TableColumn<Name, String> ratingCol =   new TableColumn<>("Rating");
    ratingCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().ratingProperty().asString());
```

Comment: no need for internal properties if you don't use them as such, that is expose as properties to allow getting rid off the errorprone PropertyValueFactory ;)